# Adding tuple to dictionary only if condition is true

Tags: python, dictionary

The following code:

```
json_c = [dict([("id", place.id),
            ("address", place.address),
            ("city", place.city),
            ("lat", place.lat()),
            ("lng", place.lng())]) for place in dataset.places.all()]
```

generates the following Json:

```
[{
    city: "city1",
    id: "1",
    address: "address1",
    lat: 32.070123,
    lng: 34.7938112
},
{
    city: "city2",
    id: "2",
    address: "address2",
    lat: 35.7938112,
    lng: 30.7938112
},
...]
```

The functions: `place.lat()` and `place.lng()` can return `None`: in this case I want to omit the lat/lng fields and to generate something like:

```
{
    city: "city3",
    id: "3",
    address: "address3"
},
...
```

any idea how to adapt the code above so it will support both cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a function to produce the dictionaries here:

```
def serialize_place(place):
    res = dict(id=place.id, address=place.address, city=place.city)
    lat, lng = place.lat(), place.lng()
    if lat is not None:
        res['lat'] = lat
    if lng is not None:
        res['lng'] = lng
    return res

json_c = [serialize_place(place) for place in dataset.places.all()]
```

for example, or use a custom `default` function for the `json.dumps()` function that handles places similarly.

You could also filter after the fact:

```
json_c = [{k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if v is not None} for d in json_c]
```

(use `d.items()` in Python 3), which would remove all values from the dictionaries that are `None`.

Comment: I think I'll use your upper solution. Regard the second one: 1. In using python 2.7.6. 2. I prefer to loop over these places only once - it would be more efficiency - Thanks!

Comment: @ItayB: I couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adapting your code, another approach would be to add a post processing step. This would be cleaner to read and make your intent more obvious

**Implementation**

```
data=[{
    'city': "city1",
    'id': "1",
    'address': "address1",
    'lat': 32.070123,
    'lng': 34.7938112
},
{
    'city': "city2",
    'id': "2",
    'address': "address2",
    'lat': None,
    'lng': None
}]
# Remove any non existing values
data = [{key:value for key, value in item.items() if value} for item in data]
```

**Output**

```
pprint.pprint(data)
[{'address': 'address1',
  'city': 'city1',
  'id': '1',
  'lat': 32.070123,
  'lng': 34.7938112},
 {'address': 'address2', 'city': 'city2', 'id': '2'}]
```

**Another approach**

Here essentially I have created a generator so that you only need to iterate the list once. This would essentially be efficient for larger lists.

```
from itertools import izip
keys = ["id", "address", "city", "lat", "lng"]
json_c = ((key, getattr(key)) for place, key in izip(dataset.places.all(), keys))
json_c = {key: value for key, value in json_c if value}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand, but would that make problem with this approach. After all the end result have just values from properties or from method calls. May be I didn;t understand your point.

Comment: @Abhijit: this Json contains thousands places, half of them might be without lat/lng - that's why i'm trying to drop them away.. (shorter json) but thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I see you have augmented your answer with something similar to mine. Do you want me to delete this answer as it would just duplicate the response without any benefit.

Comment: @Abhijit: I'd never ask others to delete posts just because there is an overlap in what we cover. :-) Competition is good!

Comment: @ItayB: I understand. In that scenario, you may want to evaluate the alternate approach

Comment: @Abhijit: this could be elegant solution if I had GIVEN json - but I'm generating it so I prefer to do it once. Thanks anyway!